# How does twitter live-update your timeline?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, twitter

Thanks for reading.

We are developing a web app. and we're finding out how to live-update some counters and info in the client side, without use scheduled-Json-Updates (yes, timeouts works... but there should be another way ; )

So I was looking at Twitter... they live-update our timeline don't they?

I cannot see the timeline updates in the XHR FireBug window. but they are happening : O

**So how does twitter live-update our timeline?**

Or

**How could I update info scalable and efficiently in the client side via ajax?**

Comment: Heh, the eternal mystery! It has been asked on SO, I'll try and find the duplicate.

Comment: Twitter uses JSONP which uses a `<script>` tag to transport data. To see it happening look at the net window set to "all" instead of just the XHR logging. Also, you should see it at least once using Firebug's DOM inspector to see it inject or modify a script tag in the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here: [**Prevent logging of AJAX calls in console tab of Firebug like Twitter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996442/prevent-logging-of-ajax-calls-in-console-tab-of-firebug-like-twitter)

Quoting the answerer, brianng:

> Note the callback `processSummizeRefresh.`
>
> Since the call is being made to a subdomain (integratedsearch.twitter.com), JSONP is being used which injects a script tag to make the request.
>
> No special FireBug hiding magic :)